# While-loop scoping in Python 2.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, scope

I am new to Python, and here's a question that is really confusing me:

```
i = 1
def foo():
    while i < 5:
        print 'in while loop'
        i += 1
foo()
```

This code produces an error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

Why isn't the *while* loop seeing the global *i* ?
As explained in the LEGB-rule, Python will search for the variable name sequentially until eventually searches in the global scope ?!

Why do I have to explicitly refer that *i* is global by adding *global* keyword:

```
i = 1
def foo():
    global i
    while i < 5:
       print 'in while loop'
       i += 1
```

On the other hand here foo prints the global value for *i*, '1' without adding global keyword.

```
i = 1
def foo():
    print 'i equals %d' % i
```